# Unique id for label input pairs

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to generate unique id for label & input pairs.

After googling I now know that, unlike with handlebars, there is no array @index syntax extension in spacebars yet (also anybody knows why [Blaze](http://meteor.github.io/blaze/) development has been inactive since the version 0.1 for past 5 months?).

So I ended up using the JS Array .map() solution inspired by [this blog post](http://evgenys-blog.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/index-in-each-expression-meteor.html) and other posts. However, this solution returns label & input pairs of objects which DOM appears to be rendering the same on 'pagination' through Session.

Live example: http://meteorpad.com/pad/NXLtGXXD4yhYr9LHC

- When clicking on first set of "Non-Indexed IDs" checkboxes, then next/previous, DOM will display new set of checkboxes correctly.
- However clicking on the second set of "Indexed IDs" checkboxes below, then next/previous, DOM seems to retain the same checkboxes because one selected from the previous page remains checked on the next page.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

I also put [the code on github](https://github.com/pemoke/meteor-unique-label-input-id) for quick testing & refinement:

Comment: I think I've isolated the inconsistency down to this: http://meteorpad.com/pad/d9PBe59Mf6tMkdipR  When you #each over an array of strings, the form state is not preserved; when you #each over an array of objects the form state is preserved. I don't know why.

Comment: Great isolation, ta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, which I've found by looking at the [`ObserveSequence` source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/23547b7c06eb1001a41ca9f20c7393e7f3360744/packages/observe-sequence/observe_sequence.js), appears to be to give your generated objects a unique field called `_id` (generated like `{{questionId}}:{{questionIndex}}:{{choiceIndex}}`). See this meteorpad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/2EaLh8ZJncnqyejSr

I don't know enough about Meteor internals to say why, but this comment seems relevant:

```
// 'lastSeqArray' contains the previous value of the sequence
// we're observing. It is an array of objects with '_id' and
// 'item' fields.  'item' is the element in the array, or the
// document in the cursor.
//
// '_id' is whichever of the following is relevant, unless it has
// already appeared -- in which case it's randomly generated.
//
// * if 'item' is an object:
//   * an '_id' field, if present
//   * otherwise, the index in the array
//
// * if 'item' is a number or string, use that value
//
// XXX this can be generalized by allowing {{#each}} to accept a
// general 'key' argument which could be a function, a dotted
// field name, or the special @index value.
```

When the `_id` is absent, it uses the index in the array, so I guess `ObserveSequence` assumes it's the same object with changed fields, rather than a different object, so it re-uses the old elements rather than destroying them and recreating them. I suppose the name `_id` is chosen so that it works well with arrays generated by `.fetch()` on a Minimongo cursor.

I don't know if this is documented behaviour, or if it might change in the future.

Comment: Great, thank you very much, would buy you a beer! ;) Btw, how did you know where to look in the source?

Comment: Well I searched the [codebase](http://github.com/meteor/meteor) to find where `#each` is implemented, and saw a reference to `ObserveSequence`, so then I searched for that.